# db_insert throwing up "Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined"

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, pdo

I've got a form in a Drupal module I'm trying to submit to create an "event". The events table structure is:

- an event id
- a city id
- an event name
- a created field
- a picture field
- a time field
- a date field
- a data field
- an event type field (which is of type enum)

When I try to create a new event and insert it into the database using:

```
$eid = db_insert('events')->fields(array(
'cid' => $cid,
'name' => $name,
'time' => $time,
'date' => $timestamp,
'data' => $extra_info,
'event_type' => $checked,  //this is an array of checked checkboxes
))->execute();
```

it throws up an error saying:

```
PDOException :SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined: INSERT INTO {events} (cid, name, time, date, data, event_type) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5_Games, :db_insert_placeholder_5_Other); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 1 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => Name [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => 23.30 [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => 1313020800 [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => More [:db_insert_placeholder_5_Games] => Games [:db_insert_placeholder_5_Other] => Other ) in event_creation_submit().
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: `date` is a reserved word in MySQL. Rename that field to something else and it will probably work. Giving this as a comment because I'm guessing :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help - changed the names of any Date fields but the problem is still there. Thanks for the help though

Comment: May you report the database schema used for the "events" table? It seems you are not passing a value for a field that the query is expecting.

Comment: eid is an int and the primary key, cid is a foreign key to another table (cities), name is just a a varchar(60), created is a timestamp, picture is a path to the picture of the event (varchar 128), time is a varchar too, event_date is a date type, data is a varchar(256) and the event_type is an enum type with 11 possible options.

Comment: Not sure if that's what you needed though?

Comment: Yes, there are some fields I am not passing (eid, created, picture). But as far as I understand: eid is on auto increment - does it not create itself when inserting a row? created's default is set to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and picture is allowed to be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to fix the situation.

Changed the type of the `event_type` field to a set and passed it a string of values instead of an array. This solved it.

Thanks for everyone's help though!